# Table stats are not getting updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, rdbms

We are facing a strange scenario in SQL Server 2016. We have a table with more than 300000 rows.

We have an index created on the table. We are using this table as part of join (note: columns in join close have index created), but query optimizer is doing a table scan.

When we checked stats:

```
RowsInTable    RowsSampled
  NULL          NULL
```

Then I ran:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS tablename
```

Stats did not change.

Then we tried to rebuild the index:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.tablename
REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,
              STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON)
```

But again: stats did not change.

We have verified there was no bulk update / insert / delete has happened.

Please help.

Comment: Did you  try FULLSCAN option in the  update statistics statement.

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue? Is your query slow? If it is slow, why do you think this is because of the engine performing an index scan? It will be better to post your actual query in order to see what's going on and what can cause the performance issue.

Comment: yes I am seeing this in actual execution plan...

Comment: Is the problem index a filtered index? When you see `rows=null, rows sampled=null` like that it's sometimes a filtered index that's empty because the filter expression doesn't match anything.

Comment: No it is simple index and it very strange

Comment: Can you include the entire first result set from `dbcc show_statistics ('tablename', 'indexname')` in the question? I'm assuming that's where you got RowsInTable and RowsSampled from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried so many combinations with statistic but did not helped out .

At last we tried below and it worked.

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.Tablename
REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON)
```

**Note** : This we should be think twice before doing in prod . We should know what is the data size of table else we will have blocking.

We still not sure what cause this type of behavior but I am suspecting we were having index on heap (non cluster unique index).

Comment: How is this different from what you tried initially? The script looks the same